# Unable to Implement WifiDirectDemo Sample in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement WifiDirectDemo sample given in the android documentation. A Guide is given here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

and the full code in the samples directory of documentation.

The class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver is giving an an error that the fragment with ids frag_list and frag_detail  does not exist although i have checked its presence in main.xml.

Here is the Error Log :

Generating resource IDs...

Handling BuildConfig class...

Generating BuildConfig class.

Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication11\bin\classes

C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication11\src\com\example\android\wifidirect\WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
                manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));

symbol:   variable frag_list

location: class id

Thanks in Advance for Any help !!

Comment: which is your minimum android api to build this application ?

Comment: yeah... it says minimum sdk version = 14 on the link given and I have version 15 installed. Still not running :(

Comment: try this .https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/cv217nRKmCg

Comment: thanks a lot ! I hope this provides some help !! Other please answer as the question isnt solved yet.

Comment: yeah... actually that post is about problem while instantiating the activity and about wifiDemo, while I have a problem with wifiDirectDemo. still looking though :/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: Yeah .. I will look through that list ... but I am unable to understand why such a simple problem is coming even though the fragment is declared in main.XML of all the folders ??