# Appending an EditText from a non-activity class

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, android-activity

I am unable to append a string of text from a non activity class to an EditText view.

I have tried passing a view as a parameter to the constructor of the class.

The Basic problem is that I am unable to use findViewById in a non-Activity class.

I know this is a silly question, but I have tried a lot but simply not able to get that.

My code sample is :

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.printtesting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class keyGenerator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

      static  Vector check = new Vector();


      static protected BigInteger p= new BigInteger("161");
      static protected BigInteger q= new BigInteger("47");
      static protected Random s = new Random();
      static protected BigInteger n = new BigInteger("1");
      static protected BigInteger trails;
      static protected BigInteger lambda ;
      static protected BigInteger nsq  = new BigInteger("1");
      static protected BigInteger g = new BigInteger("1");
      static protected BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("1");

    static protected int maxbit;
    private static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");

    public keyGenerator() {
      //  p = new BigInteger(7,1,s);
                System.out.println(p.toString());
      /*  while(!isPrime(p) && ( (p.compareTo(two)==1) || (p.compareTo(two))==0) )
        {
                p = new BigInteger(7,1,s);

        System.out.println(p.toString());
        }*/
        System.out.println("P is " + p);


    //    q = new BigInteger(7,1,s);
      /*  while(!isPrime(q) && ( (q.compareTo(two)==1) || (q.compareTo(two))==0) )
        {
                q = new BigInteger(7,1,s);
        }*/
        System.out.println("Q is " + q);




        // TODO code application logic here

       // BigInteger oth = new BigInteger("132312"); 
       generateKey();

    }


    protected  void generateKey()
    {
   EditText et = (EditText) Activity.findViewByID(R.string.te);
    // N=pq
    n=n.multiply(p);
    n=n.multiply(q);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the EditText **content** to your keyGenerator class? You must be careful when sending View to a non-activity class, as it can cause leak if the non-activity class exceeds the life of the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass Context of Edittext Activity Class to Non keyGenerator Class as :

```
Context conn;
public keyGenerator(Context con) {
conn=con;
//Your Code...
}
```

Now you can append text on keyGenerator to Edittext as:

```
EditText et = (EditText)conn.findViewByID(R.string.te);
et.append("your text here");
```

You can pass Current Context to keyGenerator constructor as:

```
keyGenerator obj=new keyGenerator(Current_Activity.this);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Please answet his questions too !!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339542/cant-get-bluetooth-adapter-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226072/unable-to-implement-wifidirectdemo-sample-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because findViewByID is an instance method, not a static method.  You need to do one of two things:

1)Pass the activity to this class as a parameter.  This would allow you to call findViewByID on it

2)Pass the EditText as a parameter (after having called findViewByID in the activity class).  This would allow you to just call setText on it

Comment: Did you mean this ??


    protected  void generateKey(Activity a)
    {
   EditText et = (EditText) a.findViewByID(R.string.te);
    // N=pq
    n=n.multiply(p);
    n=n.multiply(q);
    

Still gives an error :(

Comment: looks like Second worked by the way!! Just let me make a final verification!!

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText et = (EditText) Activity.findViewByID(R.string.te);
```

You need to pass the activity var from the activity.

```
EditText et = (EditText) (activity var).findViewByID(R.string.te);
```